# Canola Oil - Kitnyos?

Tags: passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, oil

What is the status of Canola Oil for Passover?

Is it considered as kitnyos, and therefore forbidden to Ashkenazim?

Is there a definitive answer?

Answer (score 4):

[CANOLA OIL](http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/canola-oil/) from the Orthodox Union.

> Canola oil, which is a form of rapeseed oil, should be considered kitniyot.

The Star-K (Baltimore Va'ad Hakashrus also lists Canola Oil in its list of [Kitniyos](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-HandyKitniyosGuide2011.pdf)

[CRC](http://www.crcweb.org/Passover/FAQ%20for%20Pesach%20Guide%202012.pdf) goes into the details as to why rapeseed oil (Canola oil) is considered kitniyos (based on Maharsham I:183 that it was used in Europe). Note that the CRC does not say that the Maharsham holds that it is asur (see the third permitted link in the answer by @DoubleAA ). The CRC uses the Maharsham to prove that rapeseed was used in Europe at that time and is therefore subject to the halacha of kitniyos. This disproves the claims of those who say Canola Oil was only used beginning in the 1970's.

While this seems to be the way most kashrus organizations rule (at least outside of Eretz Yisrael), there are those who allow kitniyos oils and those who do not consider Canola Oil as full kitniyos. Check your LOR before choosing to follow any ruling.

An example of those who consider Canola Oil mutar (because of the way it is processed) can be found at [Beit Eil Yeshiva Center](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=1400)

Note that when you follow a particular posek or organization, you must follow both the Chumros (strictness) and kulos (leniencies) of that posek (be consistent). Someone who always chooses the stricter or more lenient of rulings could wind up violating halacha.

Comment: Source for your second-to-last sentence?

Answer (score 4):

There is no definitive answer. [Some](http://lifeinisrael.blogspot.com/2014/04/rabbanut-says-canola-oil-is-not-kitniyot.html) [links](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=1400) [permitting](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1386&pgnum=189) and [some](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/kitniot_list/) [forbidding](http://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/canola-oil/) and [some](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/871998/jewish/Know-Thy-Beans.htm) [equivocating](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/moadim70/05-70moed.htm). It's hard to say either side should be viewed as violating halacha.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22080&pgnum=55 seems he would permit

Comment: http://www.ravaviner.com/2009/04/shut-sms-14.html permits

Comment: Internet Archive link for Rav Aviner, since original is 404'ing at the moment: https://web.archive.org/web/20210304001705/http://www.ravaviner.com/2009/04/shut-sms-14.html

Answer (score 0):

I heard from R. Nota Greenblatt that R. Moshe Feinstein held that all kitniyos derivatives are permitted. This is his psak as well.

Answer (score -1):

The Rabanut in Israel has come out saying that it is not kitnyiot. 
Source: http://tinyurl.com/ltsgkoz
It also should be noted that Rabbi Moshe Feinstein z"l says that foodstuffs that were not known at the time of the development of the custom of kitnyiot cannot become kitnyiot (Iggerot Moshe, Orach Chaim 3:63) and since Canola Oil was developed in the 1970's, you have another source to continue to use it on Passover, even if you hold by the custom of refraining from eating kitnyiot on Passover.
A full lesson on the subject can be found from the Virtual Beit MIdrash: 
http://vbm-torah.org/archive/moadim70/05-70moed.htm

Comment: They had rapeseed oil of different cultivars 150 years ago. And your links are already in my answer. So -1

Comment: I added a link to the CRC pointing out that the Maharsham says that rapeseed oil was used in Europe. This is one of the reasons that the CRC considers it (as marketed as Canola Oil) kitniyos.

Comment: @sabbahillel The Maharsham (quoted in my answer) says that Canola Oil is fine for use on Pesach unless you have a specific tradition to avoid it.

Comment: @DoubleAA The point of my pointing to the CRC is that it says that the Maharsham was showing that it was used in Europe in his time. They are not saying that the Maharsham said that it was asur, just that he discussed that type of seed. I will make it clearer.